# Visual Studio not able to push LFS files to TFS Git repo correctly

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, team-foundation-server

I have a Git repo on a TFS2018 server. On my local env I have Visual Studio 2015 and Windows Git client version 2.20.0.windows.1 including git-lfs 2.6.1 installed. I tried the following:

1. From Visual Studio, clone the repo
2. Open a Word doc that's tracked in LFS, edit, save
3. From Visual Studio, commit the change
4. From Visual Studio, push to remote
5. From the TFS web interface, download the Word doc

When I try to open the downloaded Word doc, I get an error saying the file is corrupted. When I subsequently try to clone the repo again, I also get an error saying "smudge filter lfs failed" for the file. This tells me that the LFS file was not correctly pushed to the remote.

However, if I do the exact same thing except using command line to push in step 4 instead of Visual Studio, I get no such errors -- I can open the downloaded Word doc and also clone the repo again successfully including the Word doc.

Is there a bug in Visual Studio 2015 when pushing LFS files to remote?

Thanks.